# How can I change the numColumns of Flatlist when changing the orientation

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, orientation, tile, flatlist

I created the function name getOrientation() and put it at useEffect so that whenever I rotate the device, it will rerender the component and show me which orientation the device is.

I also created the variable to determine the orientation by using hook

**getOrientation()**

```
const [orientation, setOrientation] = useState("")

const window = useWindowDimensions()
const getOrientation = () => {
    if (window.height < window.width) {
        setOrientation("LANDSCAPE")
    } else {
        setOrientation("PORTRAIT")
    }
    return orientation
}
```

**at useEffect**

```
useEffect(() => {
    getOrientation()
})
console.log(orientation)
```

My problem is that I want to set the numsColumns = 2 in Flatlist (LANDSCAPE) and equals to 1 for the portrait mode but the error popup telling me that I cannot change the numColumns on the fly. What should I do ?

**Here is my flatlist**

```
<View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
            contentContainerStyle={{
                paddingLeft: insets.left,
                paddingRight: insets.right,
            }}
            data={dishes.dishes}
            numColumns={orientation == "LANDSCAPE" ? 2 : 1}
            renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
             
                <Tile
                    style={styles.tileItem}
                    key={index}
                    title={item.name}
                    caption={item.description}
                    onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Dishdetail_Screen', { dishId: item.id })} // passing infor from one to another screen
                    // chevron={false}
                    featured
                    imageSrc={{
                        uri: baseUrl + item.image
                    }}
                />
             

            )}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()} />
    </View>
```

**This creepy error**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0WkY.png)

*P/s: I'm the fresh React-Native developer. Thanks everyone who is checking my problems*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a key prop to your Flatlist like so with the value being ur orientation:

```
 <FlatList
            key={orientation} // add key prop here
            contentContainerStyle={{
                paddingLeft: insets.left,
                paddingRight: insets.right,
            }}
            data={dishes.dishes}
            numColumns={orientation == "LANDSCAPE" ? 2 : 1}
            renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
             
                <Tile
                    style={styles.tileItem}
                    key={index}
                    title={item.name}
                    caption={item.description}
                    onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Dishdetail_Screen', { dishId: item.id })} // passing infor from one to another screen
                    // chevron={false}
                    featured
                    imageSrc={{
                        uri: baseUrl + item.image
                    }}
                />
             

            )}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()} />
```

Comment: I get a warning that "orientation is deprecated". Is there a newer way of doing this?

Comment: Wow, it worked.